# Load data for partial sidebar.blade template from database that load for every page

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, view, laravel-5.8

I am new to laravel and need help. After login user, on the dashboard page I have partial sidebar blade template that shows the user's balance data that load from database. This must be loaded for every dashboard pages.

I can not imagine how to create a controller for this user' balance since every pages have their own routes and controller.

```
public function getBalance()
{   
    $userbalance = \App\UsersBalance::where('userid', '=', Auth::user()->id)->first();
    $balance = $userbalance->balance;

    return view(......);
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Kenny's answer is good if you want to share the data with **all** pages.  However, if you only want to share with user dashboard pages and not the entire website, you probably want to use **view composers**.

https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/views#view-composers

```php
<?php

namespace App\Providers;

use Illuminate\Support\Facades\View;

class AppServiceProvider extends ServiceProvider
{

    // ...

    public function boot()
    {
        // limit returning the balance to only your dashboard layout
        view()->composer([
            'layouts.dashboard'
        ], function($view) {
            $userbalance = \App\UsersBalance::where('userid', '=', Auth::user()->id)->first();            
            view()->share('balance', $userbalance->balance);
        });
    }
}
```

This will pass the `$balance` variable to all pages that extend `layouts.dashboard`.  You can change this layout name as necessary, or even add additional layouts since the view composer accepts an array.

Comment: @matticustard answer is on point. The OP should follow this path (and accept this answer), I totally missed the bit where you mentioned "dashboard pages". +1

Answer (score 1):

You could [share data with all your views](https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/views#sharing-data-with-all-views). From the docs:

> #### Sharing Data With All Views
>
> Occasionally, you may need to `share` a piece of data with all views
>   that are rendered by your application. You may do so using the view
>   facade's `share` method. Typically, you should place calls to share
>   within a service provider's `boot` method. You are free to add them to
>   the `AppServiceProvider` or generate a separate service provider to
>   house them (...)

So, you could make your query there and then pass it to every view:

```
<?php

namespace App\Providers;

use Illuminate\Support\Facades\View;

class AppServiceProvider extends ServiceProvider
{

    // ...

    public function boot()
    {
        $loggedInUser = auth()->user();
        View::share('loggedInUser', $loggedInUser);
    }
}
```

So even tough your controller doesn't return this value:

```
# MyController.php

public funcion myFunction()
{
    return view('my_view');
}
```

You could access the properties defined globally:

```
# my_view.blade.php

<span>{{ $loggedInUser->name }}</span>
```